# Referencing the correct python module in a python project

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to create a CLI. My project structure looks like below:

```
project
|--invoices
  |--abc_company
  |--xyc_company
|--scripts
 |-- __init__.py
 |-- extract_xyz_data.py
 |-- extract_abc_data.py
 |-- extract_data.py
 |-- utilities.py
 |-- abc_validation.py
 |-- xyz_validation.py
|--main.py
```

the main directory has one of the sub-directory called "Invoices" which has two sub folders with pdf files.

It also has a scripts directory which consists of a bunch of python scripts/modules.

I want to run the main.py in terminal and pass a bunch of arguments. main.py has argparser to capture those in the main function called

```
def main()
```

I need to call extract_data.py script from this main.py script and within that script need to call the function extract_data and pass certain arguments to it for it to run.

Is this the correct way?

```
from scripts.extract_data import extract_data
```

right at the top of main.py script? I have added **init**.py in scripts folder to make it work as a module.

Also, later in the same main.py script, I need to access `abc_validation.py` from scripts directory. That script has some constant variables at the top and a class AbcValidation. The Constant variables are accessed by one of the method of this class in the script.

I need to access that class and call a method from that class in the main.py script.

If I do

```
from scripts.abc_validation.py import AbcValidation 
abc_obj = AbcValidation(args)
abc_obj.abc_main()
```

the issue is will those methods inside the abc_main function be able to access the constants defined on top of the abc_validation.py if accessed like above from main.py?

Comment: Yes, they will. The module is initialized as if it was fully imported, but only what you import is available at your file.

Comment: what abt the second part? The abc_validation.py script has a bunch of constant variables at the top then a class AbcValidation. If I import like above, then how wud the abc_main method of abc_obj in main.py wud have access to those Constants defined at the top of the script if all we do is import the class part from that module?

Comment: something weird is happening . I ran the main.py and nothing happens. No error nothing but I dont see any output. I have the if __name__ in the bottom of the code where I run the other module

Comment: The module you import has full access to itself, even though it is not fully imported. Abt the output, I would need to see some code... Remember the `if __name__ == "__main__"` is true only in the file you executed directly. If you ran the program as `python main.py` then only in main.py the block inside this if would run